# Why is Powershell ignoring my quotation marks?

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I have a Powershell script and no matter what I try it completely ignores any quotation marks in the script. The error occurs when I run the script from my VB.NET code yet, I have been running scripts successfully through VB.NET for a while now.

For example, my script starts with finding out the server name...

This works:

```
$name = gc env:computername
```

This does not:

```
$name = "SERVERNAME"
```

The error given is something along the lines of $name = SERVERNAME is not recognized as a cmdlet.... and so on.

This is causing several lines in my script to fail and the error message always displays the command WITHOUT the quotation marks.

Comment: I think divulging the method by which you are running the script from your VB.NET code will shed a lot of light on the actual problem.

Comment: What Joel said, I bet something is going wrong on the VB side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning string values you have to quote them (single or double quotes).

$name = 'SERVERNAME'

or

$name = "SERVERNAME"

or assign it directly to a variable (doesn't require quotes):

$name  = $env:COMPUTERNAME

Comment: For some reason, it works with single but not doubles. It's very weird but it works so whatever. If I have time to investigate some more, I will post it here. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with doing it from vbs, but the symptoms indicate the parser is discarding the quotes.  If you double-qoute the strings:

$name = ""SERVERNAME""

It should discard the outer set, and leave you with the inner set.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim name As String = "SERVERNAME"` maybe?